# Einstein Activity Capture implementation - what sandboxes to use?

Tags: sandbox, architecture

To integrate Salesforce and Gmail for about 2000 users, I am implementing [Einstein Activity Capture](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.einstein_sales_aac.htm&type=5) in an existing org (brownfield) which has already run for a few years. I am hesitant to roll it out directly in production, but also, I don't know how many [sandboxes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_environments.htm&type=5) do I need to test it properly.

Is it reasonable to use one full-copy sandbox for development and also for UAT? I was thinking that perhaps one developer sandbox for configuration test and one full-copy for UAT would also do the trick.

I would be grateful for an advice from someone more experienced. Thank you.

Comment: normally, one doesn't do dev in full copy sandboxes (as these are used for UAT, scalability testing, and/or 3rd party integrations) so it sort of depends on what other things you are doing in the full copy sandbox now

Comment: @cropredy So, if we have a running full copy which is used for other things, I probably should ask for another dev sandbox and test the configuration there, right? If the full copy is not being used at all, I can do dev there? Is this good reasoning?

Comment: I'd start with dev if it were me but it would be hard to get 2000 users plus Gmail messages loaded into a dev sandbox to do real testing of usefulness of EAC; hence I could easily see using the fullcopy sandbox before too long. Dev can help sort out implementation issues and deployment elements

Comment: @cropredy Thank you.